# Jquery preventDefault not workign after field validation

Tags: jquery

The following code is meant to validate an input is not blankt, and then submit the form via Ajax. It work works fine when the validation is removed, but when it is in place the preventDefault does not appear to be effective.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "input[class='p']", function(e){

  if (e.which == 13) {

    if($(this).val() == ''){        \\\\ Validation
        alert('The Field Empty');
        return false;
        }

  e.preventDefault();  

  var theData = $("form").serializeArray();
  var parentDiv = '#theDiv';

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "functions.php",
  data: theData,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $(parentDiv).html(data);
          }
       })
     }
  });
```

I have tried moving the preventDefault to above the validation but this doesn't work either.
Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Jules

EDIT : Edited to correct an error with the validation checking procedure which is not relevant to the problem being discussed.

Comment: I guess you want to prevent form to be submited when user press "return" on an input submit element, right?

Comment: `$(this).val('')` You should put `$(this).val() != ''` or you are not testing but affecting !!!

Comment: I have set up a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve on JFiddle so you can see exactly what I am getting at. jsfiddle.net/Moosheep/eGdff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit and thanks for this solution goes to TCHdvlp...

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) 
        event.preventDefault();
  });

$(document).on("keydown", "input[class='p']", function(e){

    if (e.which == 13) {

if($(this).val() == ''){ 
    alert('Field Empty');
    return false;

} 


var theData = $("form").serializeArray();
  var parentDiv = '#theDiv';

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "functions.php",
  data: theData,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $(parentDiv).html(data);
      }
       })


   }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).val('')` You should have put `$(this).val() != ''` or you are not testing but affecting !!! That's why your validation must be breaking your code.

Comment: OK, that was a stupid mistake, but it hasn't resolved the problem! I am getting the validation alert, and then the form is being submitted.

Comment: What if you place the `preventDefault()` before the validation now ? In fact, I wonder how the event is red. By saying `e.preventDefault()` you cancel the default behaviour of keydown on an input. BUT, does the 'enter' key have a specific handler ? Like, if 'enter' is pressed anywhere on the document, look for a form and submit it. You should write `$(document).on("keydown", function(e){  if(e.which == 13){e.preventDefault()})});` in the `document.ready` MWell, I'm sure you understand what I mean.

Comment: I have set up a simplified version of what i am trying to achieve on JFiddle so you can see exactly what I am getting at.
http://jsfiddle.net/Moosheep/eGdff/

Comment: I had a go at adding the preventDefault to the document.ready as suggested, but no joy.

Comment: just edited your fiddle. Seems to work. I applied a global preventDefault for enter key. http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/eGdff/1/